# Execute php file from bash script as www-data using crontab

Tags: php, bash, cron

I am trying to run a php file every night at a certain time using crontab, however the php needs to be running as a www-data because of the directory permissions. To run it as `www-data` I am using the `root` crontab and changing the user in there, like so:

`* 20 * * * sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/env TERM=xterm /path/to/dailyProc.sh`

dailyProc is as follows

```
today=`date +"%d%m%y"`

year=`date +"%y"`

dm=`date +"%m%d"`

`tar -zxf /path/to/input/$today.tgz -C /path/to/output`

echo "starting data proc"

`/usr/bin/php5 -f /path/to/dataproc.php date=$dm year=$year`

echo "data proc done"
```

All other commands in dailyProc.sh work but the php doesnt run. The php is using an output buffer and writing it to a file, which works fine calling it from the command line but doesnt work when calling by cron.

I can also definitely run dailyProc.sh from the command line as `www-data` using

`sudo -u www-data dailyProc.sh`

and everything works as expected.

Is there any reason I would not be able to run this php file in `dailyProc.sh` using crontab when everything else in it works?

Comment: Do you use `#!/bin/bash` on your script ?

Comment: There are two crontab files that run with root privileges. One is `/etc/crontab`, the other is `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`. Are you using one of these?

Comment: Check `crontab -l` to make sure your crontab is registered. Also, check the logs, probably at `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: @alex no but everything else in the script runs fine, do I need it or is it just better practice?  To edit the crontab I used `sudo contab -e` I read that editing `etc/crontab` is not a good idea beacuse the system can overwrite it?

Comment: @JohnCartwright both of those indicate that `dailyProc.sh` is being run, which it is, however the php inside it is not.

Comment: @Cob50nm: No decent system will ever overwrite `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: @lxg thanks, this is quite is quite new to me so I was going off something I read on another question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this I used curl inside dailyProc.sh

```
today=`date +"%d%m%y"`

year=`date +"%y"`

dm=`date +"%m%d"`

`tar -zxf /path/to/input/$today.tgz -C /path/to/output`

echo "starting data proc"

`/usr/bin/curl "myserver.com/dataproc.php?date=$dm?year=$year"`

echo "data proc done"
```

Answer (score 2):

Cron can be run per user too.

```
crontab -u www-data -e
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
* 20 * * * su - www-data -C "/path/to/dailyProc.sh"
```

Comment: This returned the following error  `/usr/bin/env: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `su` or `sudo` in a crontab entry, because the 6th column is for the user name anyway. And you don't need to start a terminal, because you won't see it anyway. Hence, the following should do:

```
* 20 * * * www-data /path/to/dailyProc.sh
```

The `Syntax error: word unexpected…` you mentioned in a comment appears to be inside your code. Try running the script from the command line and start debugging from there.

Comment: Is the user only a parameter if you edit `/etc/crontab` directly ? when trying this using `sudo crontab -e` I get the following error `/bin/sh: 1: www-data: not found`

Comment: When you use `crontab -e`, you're creating/editing a *personal* crontab. Then the user column is not being used and the 6th column is already the command. Edit `/etc/crontab` directly if you want the script to be executed by a different user.